# Uncountable union of multiples of measurable sets.

Tags: measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, consider the measurable space $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathscr{B}^n)$, where $\mathscr{B}^n$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Given a measurable set $A\in\mathscr{B}^n$, one can easily show that for every $k\in[0,1]$, the set

$k\cdot A=\{k\cdot x:x\in A\}$

is also measurable. What I am wondering is if we could prove or disprove (maybe with a counterexample) that for every measurable set $A\in\mathscr{B}^n$, the uncountable union

$\displaystyle \bigcup_{k\in[0,1]}k\cdot A$

is also measurable. It seems "intuitively clear" that this should be true, but so far I have been unable to come up with any truly rigorous argument to demonstrate it.

Comment: For $n=1$ it is easy as you just get an interval (possibly open or closed on either end) which contains the origin.

Comment: Similarly, in $\mathbb{R}^n$ the resulting set is a union of line segments (perhaps with missing endpoint) or rays emanating from the origin. I'm convinced the answer is easy, but I have failed miserably to produce it. Time for a bounty!

Comment: @BenPasser: The set is clearly [analytic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set) (it's the image of $[0,1] \times A \subset \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^{n}$ under $(t,x) \mapsto tx$), in particular it is Lebesgue measurable. I'm not sure it is Borel measurable in general.

Comment: Note that the statement is immediately false if $A$ is only required to be Lebesgue measurable.  In particular, any subset of the circle $S^1$ is Lebesgue measurable in $\mathbb{R}^2$, since the circle has measure zero.  If we start with a subset of the circle which is non-measurable with respect to the (one-dimensional) Lebesgue measure on the circle, the the resulting uncountable union will be a non-Lebesgue-measurable subset of the plane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a Borel set $B \subseteq [1, 2]$ such that $\{\frac{x}{y}: x, y \in B\}$ is not Borel. Then $A = B^2$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Why does such a Borel set exist?

Comment: You will need a Borel set $C$ whose difference set is not Borel. Then, set $B = \{e^x : x \in C\}$.

Comment: Rogers provides a simple construction of such a $C$ here: A Linear Borel set whose Difference set is not a Borel set, Bull. London Math. Soc. (1970) 2 (1): 41-42

Comment: Please explain why $A = B^2$ works as a counterexample. I'm not following the link from the quotient set to the union described in the question. (Is it something to do with the projection onto $S^1$?)

Comment: Yes. Consider the intersection of $\displaystyle \bigcup_{0 \leq t \leq 1} tA$ with the circle of radius 1/4 centered at origin.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you mean now. Since $B \subset [1, 2]$, $\bigcup_{t \in [0, 1]}tB^2$ is contained in the upper-right quadrant, and the open arc of the circle $\{z: |z| = \frac{1}{4}\}$ in the upper right quadrant is homeomorphic to $(0, \infty)$ by $\pi: (a, b) \mapsto \frac{a}{b}$. But the image of $\bigcup_{t \in [0, 1]}tB^2 \cap \{z: |z| = \frac{1}{4}\}$ under $\pi$ is the set of quotients from members of $B$ (it was important that $\frac{1}{4}$ was smaller than the length of any $(x, y) \in B^2$), which is non-Borel. The bounty is yours for the taking.

Comment: Nice explanation!