# Uncountably infinite union/intersection in sigma-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

i was wondering whether it makes any difference (or whether it is even true)  that an uncountably infinite union/intersection of sets that are elements of a sigma algebra is again an element of the sigma algebra?

Comment: Generally, an uncountable union or intersection will not belong to the $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: For instance, assume that the Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ is closed under uncountable unions. Then any subset $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ would be Borel, since $A=\bigcup_{x\in A} \{x\}$ and since $\{x\}$ is Borel for all $x$. This is clearly not the case.

Comment: Also see this : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423883/uncountable-union-of-multiples-of-measurable-sets

Comment: When you have the time look up the "suslin operation". It is a particular instance of an uncountable union which preserves measurability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is a set and $\mathcal B\subset 2^X$ a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, it's not true. For example, take $\mathbb R$ endowed with the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B$ of the subset of $\mathbb R$ which are at most countable, and their complements. Then write $(0,\infty):=\bigcup_{x\gt 0}\{x\}$.